# Mac terminal opens really slowly, how can I see what scripts run on open?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, iterm

When I open terminal / iTerm, it takes upwards of 7 seconds for the prompt to appear. Though I am using ZSH, I don't think it should take this long for the basic terminal to appear.

When I open the terminal, it does seem to run some "node" process.

So my question is: How do I figure out what scripts are run when a new terminal window is opened? Could it be something in my `bash_profile` file? How would I go about making my new terminal session nice and fast like it use to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the section "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES" in `man zsh`, this describes the files that are executed by zsh on startup. HTH